# File Globbing: adding *[Aa]* & *[Bb]* together

Tags: command-line, files

So basically I want to add these two cmd lines together

```
ls *[Aa]* 
ls *[Bb]*
```

I'm looking for a file that contains both A and B (lower or uppercase) and they can appear more than once.

Here's what I tried:

```
ls *[Aa]*&&*[Bb]*
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using brace expansion

One method is to use brace expansion.  Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
1a2a3  1a2b3  1b2A3  1b2b3
```

To select the ones that have both `a` and `b` in either case:

```
$ ls *{[bB]*[aA],[aA]*[bB]}*
1a2b3  1b2A3
```

#### Improvement

A possible issue is how brace expansion behaves if one of the options has no matching files.  Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
1a2a3  1b2A3  1b2b3
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ ls *{[bB]*[aA],[aA]*[bB]}*
ls: cannot access '*[aA]*[bB]*': No such file or directory
1b2A3
```

If we don't like that warning message, we can set nullglob and it will go away:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ ls *{[bB]*[aA],[aA]*[bB]}*
1b2A3
```

A limitation of this approach though, is that, if neither glob matches, then `ls` is run with no arguments and consequently it will list all files.

## Using extended globs

Let's again consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls
1a2a3  1a2b3  1b2A3  1b2b3
```

Now, let's set `extglob`:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
```

And, let's use an extended glob to find our files:

```
$ ls *@([bB]*[aA]|[aA]*[bB])*
1a2b3  1b2A3
```

Comment: Lest anybody get the idea that brace expansion is a magic wand that solves glob problems, you should probably explain that your answer is equivalent to `ls *[bB]*[aA]* *[aA]*[bB]*` — just one glob to find files containing `B` and then `A`, and another to find files containing `A` and then `B`.  (1) The brace version isn’t even any shorter than the straightforward command.  (2) If there are any files whose names contain an alternating sequence of `A` and `B`, such as `baby` or `cabstand`, they will be listed twice.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind calling `grep` for aid then

```
ls *[aA]* | grep -i b
```

will do as well.